# How can I quickly add something to a few lines in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get away from my arrow use but there is one thing I've yet to solve without using the arrow keys. Take this example:

```
var1 = "1"
var2 = "2"
var3 = "3"
var4 = "4"
```

Now I want this to be:

```
var_1 = "1"
var_2 = "2"
var_3 = "3"
var_4 = "4"
```

Using arrows I would just goto the var1, insert and add the underscore and then arrow down and do the same thing. The problem with using hjkl is I can't be in insert mode so I have to esc out, move down, insert...rinse repeat which required more work. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Comment: Oh, humbug ;-). I could see how this might not be very programming-related (I'll leave that for smarter people than myself to decide), but what I do know is that this sort of question is a great big improvement on the typical SO fare ("plz hw to maek i-PHONE MAC XCODe wwr0k on RsS thx"). This is the sort of question I'll put in my bookmarks, though it may belong in a different SE site…

Comment: @David, @Jonathan: see [this meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use a visual block insert:

- go to the "1" in "var1"
- press `CTRL+V`
- go down with `j` to select all the rows you wish to affect
- `I` (that's capital i)
- `_`
- `<ESC>`

The underscore should now be inserted at the correct place in all the rows selected (for some reason it takes a second for it to happen on my machine)

Comment: Try looking at `:h timeoutlen` to get rid of the pause exiting vblock mode.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this. Using movement commands for example:

- `1G0`  → Go to the start of the first line
- `f1` → go to the first occurence of "1"
- `i_<ESC>` → insert "_" and go back to normal mode
- `j.` → go down a line and repeat the insert command
- `j.` → go down a line and repeat the insert command
- ...

Or, better yet, use an "ex" command:

- `:%s/var/var_/`

Or even with the visual block command, as [johusman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071599/how-can-i-quickly-add-something-to-a-few-lines-in-vim/5071718#5071718) notes.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid...go back and forth from insert.

Comment: @Ryan: you are *not* going back and forth you just press `j.` ("j" followed by "."). Try it ... `1G0f1i_<ESC>j.j.j.`

Comment: @Ryan: The only way to avoid going even *once* to insert mode, is using the ex command `:s`. Every other way (visual block, navigation, macro, ...) demands that you go there *once*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're at line 1, character 1...

Using a macro:

```
qqfra_<Esc>+q3@q
```

- <kbd>q</kbd> Record macro
- <kbd>q</kbd> Into register `q`
- <kbd>f</kbd> find
- <kbd>r</kbd> 'r'
- <kbd>a</kbd> append
- <kbd>_</kbd> underscore
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> Normal mode
- <kbd>+</kbd> Start of next line
- <kbd>3</kbd> Three times
- <kbd>@</kbd> Play macro
- <kbd>q</kbd> from register `q`

Par 11.

Or (better) using [substitute](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3asubstitute):

```
:%s!r!&_<CR>
```

Par 9!

[Sorry... too much [VimGolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/)!]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer :substitute over the visual block mode.

```
%s/var\zs\ze\d/_/
```

Answer (score 0):

I always have line numbers turned on, so I'd do e.g.

```
1,4 s/var/var_/
```

This is similar to the

```
% s/var/var_/
```

answer, but it only functions on the named lines.  You can use visual mode to mark the lines, if you don't like typing the range (the `1,4` prefix) in your command.